# I can't understand how to inject Retrofit object inside my Interactor class

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger, android-mvp

I tried to read a bunch of articles, but I still can't get a grasp around dagger idea.

I have my Indicator class to which I want to inject retrofit instance.

```
public class GetForecastInteractorImpl implements MainContract.GetForecastInteractor {

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;
...
}
```

With no problem, I was able to inject it to MainActivity, but this is not what I want.

Any idea? I don't know what parts of the code would be helpful, so please tell me I would provide them.

Answer (score 1):

for injecting you have follow following procedure
lets take example of providing Retrofit(taking Kotlin as reference)
 1. Create NetModule(annotated with @Module)

for creating Retrofit you may need to provide OkHttpClient

```
@Provides
@Singleton(because we need only one instance through out the application)
fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
return OkHttpClient().Builder().build() (you can also pass other things while building like Interceptor, timeOut check docs for that)
}
```

now provide Retrofit using same format but for creating Retrofit you need to pass OkHttpClient as argument which we provided above.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder().client(okHttpClient).build()
    }
```

now you have to create Application Component annotated with @Component by providing above NetModule()

after compiling Dagger will generate that component class which you can use to inject your Classes

In above case suppose there is MainApplication class where we created AppComponent,
there is activity called MainActivity which needs Retrofit instance then MainActivityComponent will add dependencies, saying that I also need AppComponent,
then you can go ahead and use that retrofit.

let me know I was able to address your comment or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your interactor class injectable ?

Can you try to add an empty constructor in our impl class to be injectable :

```
@Inject
public GetForecastInteractorImpl () { }
```

Comment: I did try this, it didn't work. I just don't have any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Do you try to inject another dependency than retrofit ? I think it's doesn't work but you can try... It seems that your impl class is not injectable. Is your class attach to any module ?